# Cartesian product and WHERE clause issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-ase, cartesian-product

Let us have simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test
(
    c1  INT
)

INSERT INTO test (c1) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO test (c1) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO test (c1) VALUES (3)
```

Next calculate some SUM:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.c1) FROM test AS t1 , test AS t2
WHERE t2.c1 = 1
```

Output is: 6 . Simple and easy.

But if I run:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.c1), * FROM test AS t1 , test AS t2
WHERE t2.c1 = 1
```

The output is:

```
6   2   2
6   2   3
6   2   1
6   3   2
6   3   3
6   3   1
6   1   2
6   1   3
6   1   1
```

My question is: Why the second output is not matching the condition in WHERE clause?

Comment: The 2nd query is not valid. I tried it (thanks for creating an executable script!).

Comment: Are you sure this is T-SQL?  I tried running this in SQL Server 2008 [and get an error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92661/1).

Comment: Your second query isn't valid for T-SQL

Comment: Your second query doesn't compile; can you check it?

Comment: Guys I am using Sybase.

Comment: You aren't including a group clause - looks like Sybase just does the SELECT * but allows you to add a non grouping aggregate (which just sums the entire table) which produces a 6 for all rows in the output list - not sure why it doesn't honour the WHERE though

Comment: @Charleh it's not a SUM of entire table it sums over rows matching  the WHERE cause. It's totally weird :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Looks like Sybase implements it's own extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/8499;pt=8007):

> Through the following extensions, Sybase lifts restrictions on what
>   you can include or omit in the select list of a query that includes
>   group by.
>
> - The columns in the select list are not limited to the grouping columns
>     and columns used with the vector aggregates.
> - The columns specified by group by are not limited to those
>     non-aggregate columns in the select list.

However, the results of the extension are not always intuitive:

> When you use the Transact-SQL extensions in complex queries that
>   include the where clause or joins, the results may become even more
>   difficult to understand.

How does this relate to your problem?

> However, the way that Adaptive Server handles extra columns in the
>   `select` list and the `where` clause may seem contradictory. For example:
>
> ```
> select type, advance, avg(price) 
> from titles 
> where advance > 5000
> group by type
>
> type           advance
> -------------  ---------  --------
> business        5,000.00      2.99
> business        5,000.00      2.99
> business       10,125.00      2.99
> business        5,000.00      2.99
> mod_cook            0.00      2.99
> mod_cook       15,000.00      2.99
> popular_comp    7,000.00     21.48
> popular_comp    8,000.00     21.48
> popular_comp        NULL     21.48
> psychology      7,000.00     14.30
> psychology      2,275.00     14.30
> psychology      6,000.00     14.30
> psychology      2,000.00     14.30
> psychology      4,000.00     14.30
> trad_cook       7,000.00     17.97
> trad_cook       4,000.00     17.97
> trad_cook       8,000.00     17.97
>
>
>
> (17 rows affected)
> ```
>
> It only seems as if the query is ignoring the `where` clause when you
>   look at the results for the advance (extended) column. Adaptive Server
>   still computes the vector aggregate using only those rows that satisfy
>   the `where` clause, but it also displays all rows for any extended
>   columns that you include in the `select` list. **To further restrict these
>   rows from the results, you must use a `having` clause.**

So, to give you the results you would expect, Sybase should allow you to do:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.c1), * FROM test AS t1 , test AS t2
WHERE t2.c1 = 1
HAVING t2.c1 = 1
```

The `WHERE` will exclude the results from the total `SUM`; the `HAVING` will hide records that don't match the condition.

*Confusing, isn't it?*

Instead, you'd probably be better off writing the query so that it doesn't require Sybase's `GROUP BY` extensions.

Comment: That's weird and quite amazing :)